# Execute github actions workflow/job in directory where code was changed

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

I am trying to implement a **github actions workflow** with a job which will plan and apply my terraform code changes only for directory where changes were made. The problem I am currently facing is that I can't figure out how to switch directories so that terraform plan is executed from a directory where code has been updated/changed.

I have a monorepo setup which is as follow:

```
repo
  tf-folder-1
  tf-folder-2
  tf-folder-3
```

Each folder contains an independent terraform configuration. So, for example I would like **run a workflow only when files change inside tf-folder-1**. Such workflow needs to switch to working directory which is tf-folder-1 and then run **terraform plan/apply**.

```
jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  defaults:
    run:
      working-directory: ./tf-folder-1
  steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3     

    - name: Configure AWS credentials from Test account
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::000000000000000:role/deploy-role
        aws-region: eu-west-2

    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
    ...
```

So far, I have the above terraform job but it only runs for statically defined working-directory. It doesn't work with a use case where it should run the workflow when changes happen within specific folder. Can someone advise how to fix this pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to run multiple jobs based on number of directories that have been update.

In the below snippet you can see `directories` job which will check which directories have been updated, later it output an array or switch which is then used in `matrix` strategy for terraform job.

```
jobs:
  directories:
    name: "Directory-changes"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: theappnest/terraform-monorepo-action@master
        id: directories
        with:
          ignore: |
            aws/**/policies
            aws/**/templates
            aws/**/scripts
      - run: echo ${{ steps.directories.outputs.modules }}
    outputs:
      dirs: ${{ steps.directories.outputs.modules }}
  
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: directories
    strategy:
      matrix:
        directories: ${{ fromJson(needs.directories.outputs.dirs) }}
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ matrix.directories }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_CLOUD_TEAM_API_TOKEN_PREPROD }}

      - name: Terraform Format
        id: fmt
        run: terraform fmt -check

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init
      
      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform validate -no-color

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: terraform plan -no-color -input=false
        continue-on-error: true
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Actions has path filtering you can take advantage of when you are working with workflows that are triggered off a `push` or `push_request` event.

For example say you have a monorepo with the directories, `tf_1`, `tf_2`, and `tf_3`. You can do something like below for when changes occur to the directory `tf_1`.

```yaml
name: Demonstrate GitHub Actions on Monorepo 
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'tf_1/**'

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: tf_1 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
```

For more details on path filtering, please refer to the [GitHub Actions syntax documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore).

Comment: This would only work with `tf_1` directory and anything inside. Again, this is statically specifying a default working directory which needs to change based on the folder in which files have been modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GitHub action that outputs the directories where the files have changed/modified, for example, this one: [Changed-files](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files) or even perform the calculation with a shell step using `git diff`.

If you use the GHA suggested you can set the input `dir_names` to `true`, which would output unique changed directories instead of filenames, based on the results of that you can change the directory to run your Terraform operations.

Comment: This looks like a solution I needed. Is there a chance you can suggest how I would run `terraform` job (which I have in my question) for each directory returned in the output of the changed-files action?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to loop steps in GitHub Actions, so you'll likely have to repeat the Terraform actions(init, plan and apply) specifying a different `working-directory` attribute, adding a conditional to each of them to only run/execute if the directory has changes. n